# How to change the tint color of iOS system alerts?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uikit, ios11

I want to change the tint color of the iOS system alerts like the alert that ask for the photo library access or an AppStore review (not UIAlertController that you create and present programmatically) but I don't know if it is possible.

Using the window tint color like this don't work:

```
self.window?.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

Changing the tint color of the view of my view controller also don't work.

**If it is possible how to do it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible, since the system manages the creation of these alerts. You can only specify the text in the permission alerts using the key-val pair in the info.plist file. This is probably restricted for consistent UI.

Answer (score 3):

Here is Working Code for **(Swift 4)**

**1. Change the app `tintColor` in the AppDelegate.**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    self.window?.tintColor = UIColor.red
    return true
}
```

**2. Change the app `tintColor` from ViewController.**

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "This is an alert.", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.red
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I mentioned in the question that self.window?.tintColor don't work for the iOS system alerts, it is not the UIAlertController that you can create programmatically but the ones presented but iOS to request user sensitive data.

Comment: I know @adrgrondin **self.window?.tintColor = UIColor.red** it's working fine for alert and action sheet both you mention it in app delegate file.

Comment: It works for UIAlertController that you create yes I know that but not for the alert presented by iOS to request for example the access to the photo library. Try to call SKStoreReviewController.requestReview() to see an example, the window tint color is not applied to the alert.